# pyspark word cooccurrence, two RDD's

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd, distributed-computing

I'm analyzing some text to find the PMI of word pairs.

I'm trying to create an RDD using pyspark, whose entries have the following shape: for words `x` and `y`

```
((x,y), xy_linecount, x_linecount, y_linecount)
```

Where `xy_linecount` is the number of lines x and y occur together. Similarly for the other `*_linecount` variables.

I have two RDD's, `pairs` and `singles`, where `pairs` has entries of `((x,y), xy_linecount)`, and singles has entries of `(x, x_linecount)`.

I have been messing around with this for a while and haven't been able to merge my two RDD's. I was hoping to be able to inner join these two somehow, but I can't figure out how to apply the right join condition. Ideally I'd join `singles` to `pairs` twice, first on `x`, and then again on `y`...except the keys in `singles` are not of the same type as in `pairs`.

How does one get around this? I don't want to use `DataFrame`s here, just want to create the RDD I'm after.

Comment: You could use `map()` to project `x` out of `(x, y)` while keeping the pair in the RDD, i.e., `((x, y), xy_linecount) -> (x, (x, y), xy_linecount)`, `join` with the second RDD to get `(x, (x, y), xy_linecount, x_linecount)`, then map again to project out `y` and `join` again.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the reply! I ended up figuring it out on my own a couple of days ago, by doing exactly what you suggested later.